# Start inserting from the second column on bulk insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, bulkinsert

I have a table with 4 columns. I'm trying to bulk insert from a `.dat` file to a table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertIntoTable3
    @path nvarchar(500) 
AS 

declare @sql varchar(max)

select @sql='BULK INSERT Test1..Ao7 FROM ''';
select @sql=@sql+ @path ;
select @sql=@sql+''' with (FIELDTERMINATOR = ''|'' ,  ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'' )';

exec(@sql)
```

The `.dat` file has data for 3 columns, like:

```
rr  qwerwq  1
vv  asdf    1
```

I don't want to insert in the first column. I want to insert to the second, third and fourth columns.

Is there a way to start inserting from the second column on in the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a staging table, bulk insert there, and then insert only the columns you want into the destination.

Or you can [use a format file to skip columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179250.aspx).

Comment: Is there a way to do this without bulk insert?

Comment: @pyram Maybe, what are you trying to avoid with `BULK INSERT`? Since your question says "trying to bulk insert" can you clarify what it is you're trying to do and what it is you're trying to avoid? I can get to the mall without driving a car, and I have plenty of alternatives - can you tell me which one I should use?